# How to download Docker for Windows without creating account at docker.com and logging in?

Tags: docker

I do not want to register and login to docker.com, docker is open source, right? How can just download it without creating a docker account?

Comment: Link at the top that doesn't require signing in: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use docker CE (community edition)

It is published here:

https://download.docker.com/win/static/stable/x86_64/

Answer (score 1):

I also found that this direct link works without logging in: https://download.docker.com/win/stable/Docker%20Desktop%20Installer.exe